# Sum two columns in SQL where one columns needs to be negated

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to sum two columns in SQL and if the sum is greater than 0, then output it to one of the columns and if it is lesser than 0, then output to another column.

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT IF(SUM(`processed_quantity_long`,-1*`processed_quantity_short`) > 0,SUM(`processed_quantity_long`,-1*`processed_quantity_short`) AS `Position Long`,SUM(`processed_quantity_long`,-1*`processed_quantity_short`) AS `Position Short`) 
From table A 
GROUPBY date
```

It is returning me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-1*`processed_quantity_short`)>0,SUM(`processed_quantity_long`,-1*`processed_qua' at line 5

Not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: What is `-1*` supposed to do? Do you simply want to subtract the two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` does not take two arguments. Just subtract the two numbers before calculating the sum:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(processed_quantity_long - processed_quantity_short) >= 0 THEN SUM(processed_quantity_long - processed_quantity_short) END AS `Position Long`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(processed_quantity_long - processed_quantity_short) <  0 THEN SUM(processed_quantity_long - processed_quantity_short) END AS `Position Short`
FROM tablea
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong on inside if

```
 SELECT IF(
          SUM(processed_quantity_long-processed_quantity_short) > 0,
          SUM(`processed_quantity_long`-`processed_quantity_short`) ,
          SUM(`processed_quantity_long`-`processed_quantity_short`)  AS  `Position Short`
    ) From tableA GROUP BY date
```

general if statement is like below

```
SELECT IF(500<1000, "YES", "NO")
```

Or use case when

```
case when SUM(`processed_quantity_long`-`processed_quantity_short`) > 0
 then SUM(`processed_quantity_long`-`processed_quantity_short`)
 else SUM(`processed_quantity_long`-`processed_quantity_short`) as position
from tableA GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to write the code is:

```
SELECT GREATEST(SUM(processed_quantity_long - processed_quantity_short), 0) AS Position_Long,
       LEAST(SUM(processed_quantity_long - processed_quantity_short), 0) AS Position_Short
FROM tablea
GROUP BY date
```